# How to create an upload file option in wordpress within a post

Tags: php, wordpress, wiki

How can I create an upload file option in a post type which is explicit from the 'Add Media' option available as default.

I am trying to create a wiki site for an organisation wherein the authors must be able to upload files and the end users must be able to see there is an attachment with the the post.

How can I achieve it? Plz help.

I have used many plugins which only allow me to upload the files in the post once it is publised and the upload option is accessible by the end user only not the person who create the post.

I have used the plugin wp-knowledgebase for creating the wiki.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using this plugin, it will allow you to upload files from back-end.

https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-attachments/

Comment: Thank you so much. That saved my day.

Comment: Glad that it helped you :)

Answer (score 1):

One option is when you create post from admin panel you can add attachment file from media.

Step 1: Add Media (Select your file from media)

Step 2: Update post

you can follow this link

[Wp file upload form](https://wpforms.com/how-to-create-a-file-upload-form-in-wordpress/)

Comment: That is the default file uplodaing method. That would give a link between the texts.

Comment: Yes, that is default file upload method when you create a post.

Answer (score 0):

you can use this plugin. this plugin will let you upload the file.

```
 https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-file-upload/screenshots/
```

Try this step I am not sure this may or may not not allow user to download file but i am sure this will allow user to see your file in frontwnd

```
  To Upload a File in a Post:

On the Dashboard menu, click Posts, and then click Add New to display the 'Add New Post' page.
On the Upload/Insert menu, click the icon for the type of file you want to upload and the 'Add media files from your computer' page will appear.
Click the Select Files button.
In the dialog box, select the file you want to upload.
Click Open.
When your file uploads, a field appears. At the bottom of the field,   click the Insert into Post button.
```

Comment: can I link it to a post type?

Comment: Ya. I tried this already. But I am looking for something that would allow me to upload a file during creating the content/post itself.

Like an author uploading files and the reader could download it.

Comment: ok you want to upload it from back end..is that what you want?

Comment: Exactly. And the attachment should be seen in the front end too. Just the attachment, not any option to upload.

Comment: Got the solution. Thank you!